# possible to do binary classification where each sample is time series data with 100s of rows?

Tags: machine-learning

I want to use machine learning on candlestick data for hundreds of different cryptocurrencies (where each currency has 12 hours of 1 minute data, so 720 rows, and each row is timestamp, open, high ,low ,close).

Each currency will be a sample, but is there any algorithms that can take 720 rows into it? Or do I need to create features on each currencies data as a whole, for instance, the largest price change in that 12 hours, largest wick span in the 12 hours, etc.

(Or perhaps grouping the candlesticks into sections of 30 or 60 minutes and calculating the metrics for those sections, and then each section/metric combination would be a separate feature in the algorithm?)

Answer (score 0):

In your context, a $1$ minute *granularity* is too high because introduces a lot of noise due to volatility and choppiness, but this is not a valid reason for algorithms to not be able to deal with such, or bigger, objects.

If you choose your strategy, which is perfectly legitimate, it will reduce (as wanted) the dimensionality of your time series data, but will lose the *consecutio temporum* of your data (i.e., the *order matters* in time series analysis). Observe that, you can still obtain a time series, if you extract a feature for each, say, $30$ minutes (e.g., the average value) and if you do *not* treat them separately; following your example, for $12$ hours data, you will obtain a $12 \cdot \frac{60}{30} = 24$ points time series, where each point is described by several features (e.g., the average, the minimum, etc.).

If, on the other hand, you dig deeper in your application domain, given a *lower* granularity, you can obtain smaller objects (w.r.t. the length of the original $720$ points time series), which is simply raw, non-featured data.

I would try with the latter case before trying to perform feature extraction.